# Is there a Free or Opensource software like Cloud-Flare DNS ?

Tags: dns, cloudflare

Is there a Free or Opensource software like Cloud-Flare DNS ?
for example if MyWebsite.com 's server is unreachable show a custom page .

Answer (score 0):

While somewhat biased because I work for CloudFlare, the free plan does include [Always Online](https://support.cloudflare.com/entries/22050652-What-does-Always-Online-do-) & I'm not aware of any services like ours that offer something similar.

May I ask why you wouldn't just use us?

Comment: "just use us" -- Switching to a virtual dns service is a major change for this one feature.